# Extract base variable name from a factor variable

Tags: stata

Given a factor variable such as *i.income_quintile*, I want to create a program that returns the base variable name without the "*i.*" prefix (ie. *income_quintile*).

```
program define get_variable_name, rclass

    syntax varname(fv)

    return local base_variable_name = ...

end
```

Since there's many different factor variable prefixes possible (i. ib3., ib(last)., i(first)., i30., i5bn., I(5 30)bn., etc.), I would like to achieve this using built-in Stata functionality rather than using a regular expression or parsing it myself.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Shooting from the hip, wouldn't it be everything to the right of the period that separates the factor notation from the base variable name, or parenthesized collection of base variable names?

Comment: I think that'd likely work well as long as cross operators aren't used, for example, `c.age#i.group`. I'm not sure whether bambi is working with cross operators, but a single factor variable that uses a cross operator can actually involve multiple base variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `fvrevar, list` does what you need. From the [`fvrevar` help file](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?fvrevar):

> **`list`** specifies that all factor-variable operators and time-series
>           operators be removed from *`varlist`* and the resulting list of base
>           variables be returned in **`r(varlist)`**.  No new variables are created
>           with this option.

`fvrevar, list` seems to do what you want `get_variable_name` to accomplish. However, if you still wanted to write `get_variable_name`, it'd look something like this:

```
program define get_variable_name, rclass
    syntax varname(fv)

    fvrevar `varlist', list

    return local base_variable_name `r(varlist)'
end
```

Note that factor variables that use a cross operator can combine multiple base variables, for example, `c.age#i.group`. If `get_variable_name` could be used for factor variables like that, you may want to rename `r(base_variable_name)` to `r(base_variable_names)`, `r(base_varlist)`, or just `r(varlist)`.

Comment: Thanks @matthew-white. This is a great solution. I didn't mention this in my first post but I also wanted to extract the base level for a factor variable. Do you know if Stata has a way to obtain this without performing the parsing manually?

Comment: Not that I know of. I think Stata: (1) follows the `ib.` operator; or if there is none (2), follows the base level set by `fvset`; or if there is none (3) uses the variable minimum as the base level. But I don't think there's a command that extracts the level or base level of a factor variable or that splits a factor variable into its variable name and level. Like you said, parsing should be doable, but look out for the `o.` operator, which can be combined with `i.`.

Comment: Also, if `ibn.` is used, there is no base level.